# "we need money" problem even they are next to the industrial zone

Tags: simcity-2013

When I look at population detail, all my low-wealth residents are employed but they are not happy because they don't have money.

I read [How do I solve the “Shopper Unsatisfied” and “We need money” problems?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108049/how-do-i-solve-the-shopper-unsatisfied-and-we-need-money-problems)

I rezone again and try to fix traffic problem but it solve the problem for a moment and it happen again. Then I look at population detail and again all my low-wealth are employed.

Some of this sim is live next to the industrial zone but they still need money.

Comment: Hey Skyfoxs and welcome to the site. As you may have noticed we have a answer to your question already so feel free to head that way. If you need any more help the people here have figured out quite a bit of the workings of this game :)

Comment: I saw that but my low-wealth residents have job and still need money. So that answer not works for me.

Comment: @skyfoxs Then please elaborate on your question by describing your situation, referencing the other question and explaining why the answer found there doesn't work for your case, and we'll reopen.

Comment: @Shadur if he knew why the answer didn't work for his case, he wouldn't have a question.

Comment: Even my sim is next to industrial They still need money I have try to fix traffic problem rezone again it solve that for a moment and happen again I checked population detail and it told me they are employed

Comment: Don't add it in the comments, edit your question.

Comment: I saw this question last night and also the one that this got closed as a dupe for. I was thinking even though skyfoxs' problem clearly won't be solved by that answer, this will be incorrectly closed as a dupe.

Comment: Voting to reopen as he elaborated on his question.